# How to mirror Android screen to PC (USB or WiFi)?

Tags: screen

I have an nVidia Shield, and since I don't have an HDMI cable nor a monitor, I would like to stream the whole screen to my laptop. I have tried a few apps and the streaming lags. Is there a way to stream the screen without lag? It doesn't matter if the Shield is plugged in via USB, I just need to have the Shield's screen on my monitor (preferably fullscreen) and so it has no lag so I can enjoy games on a bigger screen.

Comment: which apps did you try?

Comment: There's always Chromecast.